# UITableViewCell + SDWebImage not showing/ persisting images on scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I have a `UITableView` with a  Table source and a custom cell. The custom cell consists of an `UIImageView` and two labels. The `UIImageView` image has to be downloaded from an url which needs an authentication token to download.

I am using `SDWebImage` for this. I have used the library successfully before where I had to load images within a single `ImageView`. This is the first time I am using it within a `TableView` and I cannot get it working. Here is something I have tried

UITableViewSource.cs

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = peopleHomeController.tablePeopleSearch.DequeueReusableCell("PeopleNewSearchCell") as PeopleNewSearchCell ?? PeopleNewSearchCell.Create(); ;

    if(peopleHomeController.isSearch)
    {
        var data = peopleHomeController.peopleList.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
        cell.UpdateCell(data);
    }
    else
    {
        var data = peopleHomeController.relatedPeopleList.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
        cell.UpdateCell(data);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

PeopleNewSearchCell.cs

```
public  void UpdateCell(CustomValue mValue)
{
    labelPeopleEmail.Text = email = mValue.mail;
    labelPersonName.Text = mValue.name;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mValue.mobilePhone))
    {
        labelPhone.Text = mValue.mobilePhone;
    }
    else
    {
        labelPhone.Text = "-";
    }


    var mUrl = "someimageurl";

    var manager = SDWebImageManager.SharedManager;
    manager.ImageCache.MaxCacheAge = 86400;
    manager.ImageCache.ShouldCacheImagesInMemory = true;
    SDWebImageDownloader mDownloader = manager.ImageDownloader;


    mDownloader.SetHttpHeaderValue(authToken, "Authorization");
    mDownloader.SetHttpHeaderValue("application/json; odata=verbose", "Accept");
    mDownloader.SetHttpHeaderValue("f", "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED");


    try
    {
        mDownloader.DownloadImage(
         url: new NSUrl(mUrl),
         options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.UseNSUrlCache,
         progressBlock: (receivedSize, expectedSize) =>
         {
              //Track progress...
         },
         completedBlock: (image, data, error, finished) =>
         {

             if (image != null && finished)
             {
                 InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                 {

                     this.imgPeopleProfile.Image = image;
                 });

             }
             if (error != null)
             {
                 InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                 {
                     this.imgPeopleProfile.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ic_account.png");

                 });
             }
         }


        );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }


    CALayer profileImageCircle = imgPeopleProfile.Layer;
    profileImageCircle.CornerRadius = 40;
    profileImageCircle.BorderWidth = 2;
    profileImageCircle.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
    profileImageCircle.MasksToBounds = true;
}

public override void PrepareForReuse()
{
    base.PrepareForReuse();
    imgPeopleProfile.CancelCurrentImageLoad();
    imgPeopleProfile.Image = null;
}
```

With the above code, The images are downloaded but not shown but are showing for the wrong cells on scroll. Also, when the image is shown on the wrong cell, if I do not scroll, the images disappear for the wrong cell as well. (I hope I make sense) .As mentioned in some answers on SO, I have also cancelled any image load on `PrepareForReuse()`.

I am totally bummed up with the issue since 2 days, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what does this line     var cell = peopleHomeController.tablePeopleSearch.DequeueReusableCell("PeopleNewSearchCell") as PeopleNewSearchCell ?? PeopleNewSearchCell.Create(); ;
 ?    **why did you create cell ?**

Comment: @KKRocks I have created a custom cell with an xib, so I am considering a logic where if the cell does not exist create one

Comment: Table view reuses the cell for displaying list of data. When you download an image it's not binding with the intended cell. That's why images are misplaced in cells.

Comment: then you need to check condition there if cell not exist then create cell . your existing code create cell every time .

Comment: @JitendraSolanki thanks for the reply. Can you suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: @KKRocks Makes sense. Do you this this would be the reason for the misbehavior of the sdwebimage?

Comment: yes and also there is a problem why did you use broad code ? **.you can set image as cell.ImageView.SetImage (
        url: new NSUrl ("http://db.tt/ayAqtbFy"), 
        placeholder: UIImage.FromBundle ("placeholder.png")
    );**

Comment: sdwebimage provide UIImageVIew's category class for your flexibility .

Comment: @KKRocks I need to pass a few headers like the authorization token with the url, hence I am using the broad code. Can you help me shorten it but with passing the token then?

Comment: yes but you can use that code in viewDidLoad instead of cellforRowIndexpath . you need to  use  **mDownloader** instance variable inside the cellForRowAtIndexpath.

Comment: if you write that code inside the cellForAtIndexPAth then it will be create instance every time so it will be create memory leak .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143139/discussion-between-user3034944-and-kkrocks).

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to create a cell, this will use the existing cell if it find, otherwise it will create a new one for you.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PeopleNewSearchCell", for: indexPath)as! PeopleNewSearchCell
```

Now declare `mDownloader` outside of the all methods, as it will be accessible in all your methods, like iVar:

```
var mDownloader:SDWebImageDownloader!
```

Then in your `viewDidLoad`() method setup token and other fields for the `SDWebImage`

```
var manager = SDWebImageManager.SharedManager;
manager.ImageCache.MaxCacheAge = 86400;
manager.ImageCache.ShouldCacheImagesInMemory = true;

mDownloader = manager.ImageDownloader;


mDownloader.SetHttpHeaderValue(authToken, "Authorization");
mDownloader.SetHttpHeaderValue("application/json; odata=verbose", "Accept");
mDownloader.SetHttpHeaderValue("f", "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED");
```

Now in data source method of tableView use `mDownloader` to download an image for a cell:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:   "PeopleNewSearchCell", for: indexPath)as! PeopleNewSearchCell

  if(peopleHomeController.isSearch)
  {
      var data = peopleHomeController.peopleList.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
    cell.UpdateCell(data);
  }else{
     var data = peopleHomeController.relatedPeopleList.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
    cell.UpdateCell(data);
  }

 //download an image
 try
   {
    mDownloader.DownloadImage(
     url: new NSUrl(mUrl),
     options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.UseNSUrlCache,
     progressBlock: (receivedSize, expectedSize) =>
     {
          //Track progress...
     },
     completedBlock: (image, data, error, finished) =>
     {

         if (image != null && finished)
         {
             InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
             {

                 cell.imgPeopleProfile.Image = image;
             });

         }
         if (error != null)
         {
             InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
             {
                 cell.imgPeopleProfile.Image =  UIImage.FromFile("ic_account.png");

             });
         }
     }


    );
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
return cell;
}
```

and remove the image downloading code from the `updateCell`() method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I changed to this and its still the same scenario

Comment: I cannot access imgPeopleProfile from my GetCell(), since it is in a custom cell class

Comment: Do you not have an outlet of imgPeopleProfile in custom cell class? In order to assign the value to the views of a cell, the designated views should be accessible for a cell from the data source of the tableview. So make it work, make the imgPeopleProfile view  accessible in the cell. To make it accessible you can create an outlet from xib.